# What is preventing a DHCP client from getting the default gateway route?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, raspberry-pi, dhcp-server

Raspberry PI is connect to OpenVPN server via TAP connection. PI's tap is bridged with the PI's ethernet interface.

When the the client in question connects to the pi's ethernet port, isc-dhcp-server on the OpenVPN server immediately gets polled and assigns an IP address. The client takes the IP address without any issue. However, he has absolutely no 'default gateway via ...' in his route table. If I manually add the route by entering:

```
ip route add default via 10.70.0.1 def eth0
```

Then the client works perfectly.

Keep in mind that this is not a traditional TUN VPN connection. This is a TAP connection and the VPN client is the Raspberry PI which is between the client and the server. So, no route pushing or gateway pushing by OpenVPN plays into any of this at all.

PI when connected to the OpenVPN Server:

```
root@pi-test:~# ip addr show br0
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:d5:0f:08:f3:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.70.0.201/24 brd 10.70.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:94d5:fff:fe08:f330/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 86200sec preferred_lft 14200sec
    inet6 fe80::94d5:fff:fe08:f330/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@pi-test:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id          STP enabled  interfaces
       br0  8000.96d50f08f330  no           eth0
                                            tap0
```

Client when connected to the PI:

```
me@client:~$ ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:12:3f:82:92:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.70.0.105/24 brd 10.70.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 31065sec preferred_lft 31065sec
    inet6 2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:c040:ebd3:1619:57b1/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86066sec preferred_lft 14066sec
    inet6 2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:d7f9:41bf:a910:9b43/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86066sec preferred_lft 14066sec
    inet6 fe80::cfce:6b01:c5d4:ced6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

me@client:~$ ip route
default via 10.70.0.1 dev eth0 (this line is missing)
10.70.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.70.0.105 metric 100
```

Note also that the RA's for IPv6 are working perfectly (so is the routing). Just throwing this in there as further evidence that the bridges are working as expected. Those IPv6 addresses are all part of the Server's IPv6 routed block. That 8723 address below is the server's IPv6 LL address as expected.

```
me@client:~$ ip -6 route
2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::d8ae:1bff:fe1f:8723 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

The client works as expected when plugged into another router. It gets its IP address AND the 'default via'. My expectation is that once the bridge has been built between the Server and the Client, that it should behave as though everything is physically connected. And, it almost does. No routing should play into this equation, but should anyone ask, iptables is in Accept All mode until I get this figured out.

DHCP server (I've used this same configuration many times without issue):

```
root@server:~# cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
option domain-name "local.net";
option domain-name-servers 10.70.0.1;
ddns-update-style none;
subnet 10.70.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.70.0.100 10.70.0.199;
        option routers 10.70.0.1;
}

host pi-router1 {
        hardware ethernet 96:d5:0f:08:f3:30;
        fixed-address 10.70.0.201;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from Linux seeming to strip out the gateway ["(4)Routers" in dhcpdump] in the DHCP response. OpenVPN [documents](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) this as follows:

> If --server-bridge is used without any parameters, it will enable a
>   DHCP-proxy mode, where connecting OpenVPN clients will receive an IP
>   address for their TAP adapter from the DHCP server running on the
>   OpenVPN server-side LAN. **Note that only clients that support the
>   binding of a DHCP client with the TAP adapter (such as Windows) can
>   support this mode**. The optional nogw flag (advanced) indicates that
>   gateway information should not be pushed to the client.

So then, using *nogw* appeared to have no affect on the pi - as expected since it is Linux. But when I connect a computer (any kind of client: Linux or Windows) to the pi's Ethernet port, then it actually is getting assigned a gateway. In other words, the DHCP response from the TAP'd server is making its way unedited to the clients on the other side of the pi, just not the pi itself. This last part is perfectly fine since it has its own configuration scripts and so on.

The point and the result is: any generic clients can connect to the pi as a router which is securely connected to a VPN server and they will all be assigned IP addresses (both v4 and v6) from the VPN server on the other end of the TAP without any issues.

Comment: So this seems not to be a problem of "Linux stripping out the 'routers' option", but of **OpenVPN** stripping this option. Note that the connection process of the RaspPi is different from the connection of the client - the client issues a DHCP request, the RaspPi starts the OpenVPN client (and won't issue a DHCP on the newly created tap interface unless explicitely configured).

Comment: @dirkt I understand what you are saying. But here is the thing: OVPN does not know the IP address of the OVPN client because it is purely bridged with no knowledge of IP addresses in this configuration. That said, the ovpn client gets a "filtered" response while all other devices do not. And these are all sent over the "bridged" bridge. It is strange either way. That tells me something knows that the response is destined for the MAC address of the direct ovpn client. But who knows; this is a bit baffling to me. But it works now consistently even on a non-pi router with Ubuntu & same config.

Comment: Exactly: It looks like it is somehow OpenVPN that filters out the `routers` option of the DHCP response, while forwarding the packets between the tap-interface and the tunnel. For whatever reason (possibly because OpenVPN can also set up routes when the connection is established, and doesn't want DHCP responses to override those routes).